# ubuntu 16.04. drivers required for epson stylus sx235 wireless printer

Tags: printing

I'm trying to find the correct drivers so i can print wireless to my epson sx 235 printer. When I add a printer it sees it on the network ok but the drivers recommended do nothing but freeze my computer. Any info would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by they freeze your computer?

Comment: the computer says it is installing the drivers but it installs forever